# On a matrix equation with Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, tensor-products, matrix-equations

Is there any work on the matrix equation in unknowns $X, Y \in {\Bbb C}^{n \times n}$ $$(X \otimes Y + Y \otimes X) \operatorname{vec}(A)=0$$ where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)? Or, in general, is there any work on $X \otimes Y + Y \otimes X$?

Comment: If $A$ is not the unknown, why vectorise, then? Why not write in matrix form without $\otimes$?

Comment: One can write this way too, $(X \otimes Y + Y \otimes X)v=0$ for a fixed $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: That's because I suspect the matrix $(X \otimes Y + Y \otimes  X)$ is too nice and restrictive. Which is not that apparent in the unvectorised matrix equation.

Comment: I usually do that in my work. I wanted to find out  if there are already some known results.

Comment: We can rewrite this equation as $XAY^T=-YAX^T$. If $A$ is symmetric, then $(XAY^T)^T=YAX^T=-XAY^T$, so $XAY^T$ is anti-symmetric. If $A$ is anti-symmetric, then $(XAY^T)^T=YA^TX^T=-YAX^T$, so $XAY^T$ is symmetric. But for complex matrices, it usually makes more sense to take the adjoint than the transpose.

Comment: The superoperator $\mathcal{E}(A)=XAY^T+YAX^T$ preserves symmetry in the sense that if $A$ is symmetric, then $\mathcal{E}(A)$ is also symmetric. By setting $X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(R+S),Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(R-S)$, we obtain $X\oplus Y+Y\oplus X=R\oplus R-S\oplus S$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the symmetry preserving is one of a few nice properties of the operator. This operator splits as a direct sum of its restrictions on the symmetric matrices and skew symmetric matrices.

Comment: The superoperator $\mathcal{E}(A)=XAY^T+YAX^T$ always has Choi rank at most 2.

Comment: Not familiar with Choi rank, sounds interesting. Can you elaborate or give a reference?

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}$ is the superoperator defined by $\mathcal{F}(XAY^*)$, then set $J(\mathcal{F})=\text{vec}(X)\text{vec}(Y)^*$; we call $J(\mathcal{F})$ the Choi representation of $\mathcal{F}$. We can extend $J$ by linearity, and in this case, $J(\mathcal{E})=\text{vec}(X)\text{vec}(\overline{Y})^*+\text{vec}(Y)\text{vec}(\overline{X})^*$ (here $\overline{B}=(B^*)^T=(B^T)^*$ which is the matrix obtained by replacing each entry with its conjugate). The Choi representation of a superoperator can be found in most texts on quantum information theory.